# Groovy how to combine multiple commands?

Tags: shell, groovy

I want to exec this command to get vertxHome.

In shell, I can do it like this:

```
vertxHome=$(dirname $(dirname $(readlink -f $(which vertx))))
echo $vertxHome
```

But how to do this in groovy?

I tried `vertxHome = 'dirname $(dirname $(readlink -f $(which vertx)))'.execute()`, but it not works.

Comment: Can't You just use VERTX_HOME env variable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try executing the command through the shell instead of execute the command directly, try with:

`["/bin/sh", "-c", "your_command"].execute()`

in your case:

`["/bin/sh", "-c", "dirname \$(dirname \$(readlink -f \$(which vertx)))"].execute()`

Note that as OP advice in his comment `$` must be escaped in the command.

If you want to get the output for the command you can get it through this sample code which it is from in [groovy documentation](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Executing+External+Processes+From+Groovy):

```
//A string can be executed in the standard java way:
def proc = ["/bin/sh", "-c", "dirname \$(dirname \$(readlink -f \$(which vertx)))"].execute()             
// Call *execute* on the string
proc.waitFor()                               // Wait for the command to finish

// Obtain status and output
println "return code: ${ proc.exitValue()}"
println "stderr: ${proc.err.text}"
println "stdout: ${proc.in.text}" // *out* from the external program is *in* for groovy
```

If you want to access to an environment variable and don't care about command execution use: [`java.lang.System.getenv()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/env.html), in groovy for example this could be:

```
def javaHome = java.lang.System.getenv("JAVA_HOME")
print javaHome
```

You can do the same to get `VERTX_HOME`.

Hope this helps,

Comment: Ah! So good idea how do I have never thought. Thanks. But ``$`` must be escaped, or it will raise an error.

Comment: yeahh! you're right, `$` must be escaped. I tried with simpler command. I will update the answer, thanks `:)`.

Comment: This is not good code. 1. this code is not portable, because not all OS have a `/bin/sh` shell; 2. even among Unices, only GNU has the `readlink -f` option; 3. even among GNU/Linux, `/bin/sh` is not an alias of Bash in all distributions, and only Bash has `$()`; 4. this code does not scale well, because it spawns outside processes. You should really use Java's path manipulation primitives to do this sort of thing. Or better yet, put that directory in a properties file.

Comment: @Tobia you're right, however the OP ask for do a specific command in specific environment, I show it a possible "trick" to achieve OP goal. I don't say that this is a best way to do so furthermore I suppose it's only a curiosity and it isn't for a production environment or something like that. Anyway thanks for your correction `:)`.

Comment: Of course my comment was mostly for OP. But I had to mention that this is not the proper way do to it.

Comment: Hi @Tobia . I known it's not a good idea. But I don't know how to get the absolute path of a executable program from $PATH(or %PATH%) use java or groovy. Would  you give me a sample? Thanks.

Comment: Hi @abcfy2 I update the answer to get the environment variable, take a look at `:)`.

Comment: Hi @albciff . Thanks, but it's not what I mean. For example, if ``which java`` will return ``/usr/bin/java``, and it's also a symbolic link. I want to track this link to get the real JAVA_HOME. How to do this use java or groovy? Because ``JAVA_HOME`` is not set to environment variable.

Comment: Ops @abcfy2 sorry I don't know how to do that, maybe you can ask another question specifying that you want this exactly behavior,  sorry I can't help you this time.

Comment: @albciff It doesn't matter for now. I can call a bash command to solve  this issue for the present.